# Uniform Motion: Travelling at the Same Direction

Tags: linear-algebra

Rabbit can run a lap half as fast as Turtle can. At the start of the race, Rabbit is a quarter of a lap ahead. They run in the same direction, and the Turtle caught up with Rabbit after $1$ minute. How long will it take Rabbit to finish a lap.

In this problem, I first let the running speeds (some distance unit per minute) of Turtle and Rabbit be $v_t$ and $\frac{1}{2}v_t$ respectively. Then I let the distance of $1$ lap be $L$. Since the distance travelled of both Turtle and Rabbit after $1$ minute is equal, the equation I got is $\frac{1}{2}v_t+\frac{1}{4}L=v_t$, giving me $v_t=\frac{1}{2}L$. Which means, the time travelled by Rabbit to finish one lap would be $t=\frac{L}{\frac{1}{2}L}=2$ mins. However, the choices does not include $2$ mins. In fact, $4$ mins is the correct answer. What could be wrong with my solution?

Comment: The speed of the rabbit is $v_t/2$, so $t=\frac{L}{\frac 14 L}=4$